# DirectoryNotFoundException on XMLWriter

Tags: c#, xml

There is a "Docs" folder in my project. I want to create and write into an XML file under that folder.
Here is my attempt :

```
string myPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var finalPath = Path.Combine(myPath, "Docs");

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(finalPath + @"\employees.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");...
```

I get this exception :

> {"Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\...\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\bin\Debug\Docs\employees.xml'."}

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well does the directory `...\Application6\bin\Debug\Docs` exist? Or is it actually `...\Application6\Docs`? It seems to me that it's the first line of your code that's the problem - nothing to do with `XmlWriter` at all.

Comment: As an aside, if you already have a variable `finalPath`, why don't you make it really "final" by `Path.Combine(myPath, "Docs", "employees.xml")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories in your project structure are (thankfully!) not copied to the project's output - hence when you're trying to access a subdirectory under `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` (which as you can probably see, by default = YOUR_PROJECT_PATH + \bin\ + Debug|Release), you're not able to find it.

`Directory.CreateDirectory` is your friend; as an added bonus this does nothing (does not throw any exceptions) if the directory already exists, so it can safely be used to ensure a given directory exists.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example on how to use this in my case? I couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: `[...] Directory.CreateDirectory(finalPath); using (XmlWriter [...]`